# Controllability of $x' = Ax + Bu(t)$ implies controllability of $\left \{ \begin{matrix} x' = Ax + By \\ y'=u(t) \end{matrix} \right.$

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory

Suppose that the system 
$$x'(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$$
is controllable in $R^n$, where $A$ is $n \times n$, $B$ is $ m \times n$ and $u(t)$ is $m \times 1$
Show that the system
$$\left \{ \begin{matrix} x'(t) = Ax(t) + By(t) \\ y'=u(t) \end{matrix} \right.$$
is controllable in $R^{n+m}$

**My attempt**

If the first system is controllable, then the matrix
$$M = \begin{pmatrix} B & AB & A^2B &\ldots & A^{n-1}B \end{pmatrix}$$
has rank M. Let the second system
$$\begin{pmatrix}x' \\ y' \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} A & B \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ I \end{pmatrix}u(t)$$
Then, its Kalman matrix (aka cotrollability matrix) is
$$\bar{M} = \begin{pmatrix} B & AB & A^2B & \ldots & A^{n+m-1}B \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
The matrix $A$ is $n \times n$ and, by Caylay Hamilton theorem, 
$$A^{n+l} = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \alpha_{k,l} A^{k}, l=0,1,...$$
I mean, $A^{n+l}$ is a linear combination of the first $n$ powers of $A$. This implies that we have $n$ linearly independent columns in $\bar{M}$ at the the terms untill $A^{n-1}B$ (because the first system is controllable). But I don't see how to find the other $m$ columns. What am I doing wrong?
Probably my controllability matrix is wrong, since it only can have $n$ l.i rows.

Thanks in advance!

**@Edit** We could solve it for $y$ first and return to a system only in $x'$, substituting $u$ by some $\int u$. The Kalman matrix of first and second system would be the same and, by hypotesis, it would have $\text{rank }n$, correct? But why isn't my first approach correct?

Comment: You forgot to add $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ I\end{pmatrix}$ column in $\bar{M}$.

Comment: Oh, of course! Thanks. I will try using it.

Comment: Duplicate http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/5323/controllability-of-x-ax-but-implies-controllability-of-left-begin